# Changing the Orientation Smoothly for SDK from App

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I know the question related to orientation has been asked multiple times, but I am facing some weird issue.
I am working on one SDK that has some Activity which can be opened from the App, The SDK asks for the orientation values from the App and I am updating the orientation in **onCreate()** of the Activity by setting:

```
requestedOrientation = orientation
```

It works perfectly when I am holding the device in the same orientation as the orientation is set by App. But If I am holding the device in portrait mode and setting the `requestedOrientation` to **LANDSCAPE** then my screen flickers, 1st it shows the **portrait** screen and then goes to **landscape**.
In manifest I have set the **configChanges** to `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`
I have separate layouts for both the orientations. Let me know, if anything else is also required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented a solution at our end as below, Now the clients are declaring the same Activity in their `manifest` file and replacing the orientation as per their requirements.

**SDK Manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

**Client Manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name="sdkPackage.ActivityName"
        tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
```

`sdkPackage` is the complete package of SDK, basically the client is now overriding the `android:screenOrientation` and setting it to whatever orientation they want.

Comment: @Kaizie You can give it a try and it will solve the problem of flickering.

Answer (score 2):

> But If I am holding the device in portrait mode and setting the requestedOrientation to LANDSCAPE then my screen flickers, 1st it shows the portrait screen and then goes to landscape

The screen orientation is an activity feature that can differ from activity to another. So, going from activity to another, the system has to decide ahead which orientation it should display the activity on; this is taken before `requestedOrientation` takes place; because it shows the activity with the default orientation setting; then when `requestedOrientation` get called, the activity is recreated with the desired orientation; so `onCreate()` will get called twice with different orientations; and that is why the screen flickers with the portrait orientation (the system desired one) before showing the landscape orientation (the user desired one).

[In documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen), the default `android:screenOrientation` orientation is "unspecified"; i.e., it's left up to the system to decide;

> It works perfectly when I am holding the device in the same orientation as the orientation is set by App.

Usually that defaults up to the device sensor.

But you can specify that to be "locked" for the second activity ahead (in the manifest's activity section) so that the system has no chance to decide that.

> "locked": Locks the orientation to its current rotation, whatever that is. Added in API level 18.

```
<activity
    android:name="....."
    android:screenOrientation="locked"
    .... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I went with another solution that worked for us. Basically now the client is declaring the same activity in his manifest and replacing the orientation with the orientation that they want for their app.

Answer (score 0):

You should set requested orientation based on configuration changes

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else if...
}
```

If you want to support portrait and reverse portrait together, do it with SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT.

Comment: onConfigurationChanged() gets called after the onCreate(), The problem still remains the same. My Activity in SDK first goes into portrait mode and then in landscape..